# PhoneGap - Request GPS Activation

Tags: java, android, cordova, gps

I am developing a Phonegap app for Android and would like to get coordinates from GPS.

The application is composed of the Web assets and a Background service (Java).

I get these coordinates from Java side.

But I believe from the backgorund service is not possible to request the user to turn GPS on.

How could I request to the user **activate the GPS**, using that standard intent for activating it? And Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You could use [this Diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic) for Phonegap Android.</s>

The `isGpsEnabled` function allows you to check if GPS is enabled on the Android device and `switchToLocationSettings` switches from your app to the Location settings page where the user can switch on GPS (this should be probably be preceded by a dialog asking if the user wants to do this).

**Update** I've forked the original plugin, updated it for Phonegap/Cordova 3+, documented it and extended its functionality. It can be found here: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Comment: That's what I was expecting for, to have a plug in or someway of solving this problem. Hopefully it'll help me out to achieve the desired solution.  I'll try to implement and later on will post the outcomes here. Anyway, thanks a million!

Comment: The link you provided is dead. Please update your answer, because in its current format it doesn't hold any usefull information.

Comment: [Updated link](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic). Google. 10 seconds. Now useful again.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you use the [Geolocation API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) it will ask the user for permission. Other than that you will just have to listen if the GPS is active, and if it's not you'll have to display a message requesting them to grant you GPS access, usually followed by instructions on how to do that through the device settings.

Comment: if I request getCurrentPosition for example, it'll return the coordinates regardless of whether GPS is enable or not, simply because  it gets position from the Network, that is exactly what I don't want. I'd like to "force" him (of course, if he desires and accept) to enable GPS. Any idea?